# How to auto fill a primary key(surrogate) column using hibernate

Tags: hibernate, primary-key, hibernate-annotations

I have a column named 'uniqueid' for which i need to enter **only even numbers** in increment fashion. I am using Hibernate for inserting data into the table. I came across this feature in Hibernate where the Hibernate itself inserts the data to a primary key column using the annotation **@Generated value**. But it is defaulting to incrementing the value one at a time. How can I specify the increment value to 2 starting from 2 onwards so that I get all even numbers filled automatically in my 'uniqueid' column for each object.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a custom generator which you can then declare in a class:

```
@GeneratedValue(generator="MyGenerator")  
@GenericGenerator(name="MyGenerator", strategy="somePackage.someSubPackage.MyGenerator",  
    parameters = { @Parameter(name="tableName", value="test_table") } )
```

Also your generator class needs to implement [PersistentIdentifierGenerator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/id/PersistentIdentifierGenerator.html)

Comment: I partly agree to your answer, but my expectation was "what is the format of the custom generator class?" How should I write it? What all I need to create such a custom generator class. It would be helpful if you can let me know them